# story about man injected to live very slowly

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a story about a man who is injected by some drug that makes time go very slowly for him. This drug was developed by some terrorist group I think, they were against people becoming cyborgs. They would inject themselves with this drug together with a sleep drug so they could escape the police by hiding in crypts and then wake up many years later.

The man was a guard/scientist at a science facility and almost caught them developing it, as he notices that a dead animal is actually alive but very slow. (I think they referred to the animal in a foreign language). They attack him with the slow drug but don't manage to inject the sleep drug before they have to flee.

He becomes trapped in this state as science looks for a cure/antidote, and can only come back to normal time for a single day every year or so. His daughter spends hours sitting next to him so that he can perceive her being there for a few minutes. He has a computer synced to his speed for communication but can't keep up with the outside news as it changes so fast.
He manages to go to his daughter/granddaughter's wedding I recall by passing himself off as some other relative, and at the end of the story she is police officer and gets caught by these terrorists too.

I think it is set in US/Mexico but goes far into the future when the countries are different to today, e.g. Texas is independent.

Don't know when it was published, but I heard it on audiobook within the past few years.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Syncing Forward](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27867771-syncing-forward) by W. Lawrence

> This drug was developed by some terrorist group I think, they were against people becoming cyborgs

The Terrorist group (called Millennial) were trying to stop the advancement of technology that would lead to the creation of AI becoming more powerful than humans (Singularity)

> as he notices that a dead animal is actually alive but very slow

Surveillance footage of a 'dead' rat in a cage that is shown to be slowly breathing when the footage is sped up.

> They attack him with the slow drug but don't manage to inject the sleep drug before they have to flee

In the tunnels under the Pharmaceutical company campus they have him tied to a stretcher and agree to take him with them to the crypt but only manage to give him four injections before the police turn up. They escape and leave him behind without giving him the fifth and final injection.

> He becomes trapped in this state as science looks for a cure/antidote, and can only come back to normal time for a single day every year or so.

Scientists are able to bring him back to normal for a day but he starts slowing down again which lasts longer each time.